# Letting an OVZ container use the hosts ip

Tags: debian, networking, openvz

I have a server over at OVH and it has Proxmox installed on it.

I've created a container but I want to host a server in there and I want it to use the host's external IP. How can I do this?

I hope I don't have to get a second IP for this.

Both the host and containers have Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have 2 choices here. You can either have the OVZ container have it's own IP address that is rout-able on the internet. Setting this up would require that the OVZ host (the one that contains the guests) to have his network setup as a bridge, with each OVZ container having their NIC added to the bridge. This allows them to participate fully on the LAN network as if they were physical hosts.

Your other option would be to set them up so that they're only accessible from private network that's local to the OVZ host. You would then need to use standard firewall NAT port forwarding to redirect any traffic on the externally facing IP address that the OVZ host owns to the OVZ container's private network IP.

You can read more about both of these techniques on the OVZ project's wiki.

- [Common Networking HOWTOs](https://openvz.org/Common_Networking_HOWTOs)
- [Virtual network device](https://openvz.org/Virtual_network_device)
- [Differences between venet and veth](https://openvz.org/Differences_between_venet_and_veth)

Comment: So if I want this container to be fully independent I should get a second ip and assign it to this container? can I use the ```vzctl set 101 --ipadd "the new external ip"```command?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way. In my setup I have config files for each VZ, `/etc/vz/conf`. In this dir. are files such as `101.conf`, with contents like this: `IP_ADDRESS="192.168.1.101"`. The `vzctl set 101 ...` command is manipulating this file.

Comment: But can I use an ip that is not of the ```10.x.x.x```, ```192.168.x.x``` or ```127.x.x.x```? Something like ```180.239.155.70```?

Comment: @Dominique - yes of course, as long as that machine is connected to the networked which that IP is a member of. My example only shows that subnet since that's what I'm using, but you can use any IP that's available on your network.

Comment: Fantastic, I will get a failover IP from OVH and assign it using this method, I dont need to add a veth right?

Comment: @Dominique - generally no, if the service you're running on the VM is something like Samba, then you would, but for things such as Apache/MySQL no.